# Proper way to move stable branch changes back to main in Mercurial

Tags: java, maven, version-control, mercurial

in Mercurial after you have created a stable branch, say RC1, from the main dev branch, you keep on working on the dev branch for future versions. Now if you are required to make quick fixes on RC1, which are deemed useful and are needed for the dev branch as well, do you

1. Make change on dev and create a patch for RC1 or
2. Make change on RC1 and create a patch for dev or
3. Make change on RC1 and switch back to dev and merge RC1 to dev or
4. Any other proper way to do

I tried 3., but with a slight problem, the merge also merges the pom version RC1 and those dependency versions to dev, overwriting the SNAPSHOT versions. May be I have done it wrong.

So now I am going for 2.

Please advise the proper way to do, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using option 3. This also what the [standard branching wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching) suggests. Your history will then look like this after having merged a couple of fixes from RC1 into default:

```
default:    ... a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f -- g
                      \       /              /
RC1:                   x --- y ------ z --- w
```

By merging like that, there's no chance of forgetting to include a bugfix from RC1 — you're letting the tool keep track of things instead of having to remember it yourself.

The problem you mention about the version in the `pom.xml` file being updated incorrectly is due to you updating the version *after* you created the RC1 branch. In other words, you updated it in `x` or `y` above.

Instead, I would change the version from `1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0` on the default branch before branching off. After you make the branch, you change the version to `2.0-SNAPSHOT` or whatever your next version will be. Annotating the above graph with version numbers, it will look like this:

```
              1.0-S   1.0   2.0-S  2.0-S  2.0-S  2.0-S  2.0-S
default:    ... a ---- b ---- c ---- d ---- e ---- f ---- g
                        \           /                    /
RC1:                     x ------- y -------- z ------- w
                        1.0       1.0        1.0       1.0
```

Remember, that when Mercurial is merging a file, it compares *exactly three* versions of the file:

- the ancestor version
- the local version (the version in the working copy parent revision)
- the other version (the version you are merging into the current branch)

So when you merge `y` into `c` above, these three versions of your `pom.xml` will be considered:

- the version from `b` with version 1.0
- the version from `c` with version 2.0-SNAPSHOT
- the version from `y` with version 1.0

A three-way merge is really a kind of "vote" between the three files: the file in `c` says the version should be changed to 2.0-SNAPSHOT. The file from `y` says the version can be kept at 1.0. Changes are always considered good by a three-way merge, so the merge result will be version 2.0-SNAPSHOT.